# having error (1054, "Unknown column 'order_product.id' in 'field list'") in django

Tags: django, django-models, inspectdb

I create the models file with **inspectdb**, but it gives an error when I want to show it in *Admin panel*:
`(1054, "Unknown column 'order_product.id' in 'field list'")`
In my searches, I realized I had to add a primary key to each of the models, but nothing happened when I did that.

Here is my code:

```
# models.py
class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('Orders', models.DO_NOTHING)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Products', models.DO_NOTHING)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attributes, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Colors, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    attribute_price_differ = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    attribute_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'order_product'


class Orders(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('Users', models.DO_NOTHING)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    weight = models.IntegerField()
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupons, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField()
    process_status = models.IntegerField()
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'orders'
```

```
# admin.py
@admin.register(OrderProduct)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   pass
```

Comment: It seems `id` was only added in `Orders` and not `OrderProduct`. Have you tried adding it there as well?

Comment: @bdbd yes, i tried it but it still have error and when i add "id" to OrderProduct i can't migrate it.

Comment: add id column, delete migrations files and try again, if not working, create new database and migration again